# Typescript interfaces, array of arrays of objects

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and I am struggling with creating an interface of the following result.

```
[
  [
    {
      "type": string,
      "what": string,
      "from": string,
      "to": string,
      "fee": string,
      "blockNumber": number,
      "transactionHash": string,
      "oracleRequestId": string
    },
    {
      type: string;
      what: string;
      transactionHash: string;
      blockNumber: number;
      oracleRequestId: string;
      output: string;
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "type": string,
      "what": string,
      "from": string,
      "to": string,
      "fee": string,
      "blockNumber": number,
      "transactionHash": string,
      "oracleRequestId": string
    },
    {
      type: string;
      what: string;
      transactionHash: string;
      blockNumber: number;
      oracleRequestId: string;
      output: string;
    }
  ]
]
```

I did create two interfaces for the objects in the array and merge them so that I can use `mergedInterfaces [][]`. This seems to be fine.
The issue is that sometimes I do push a different object instead of the two above, the object is

```
{
    message: string,
    code: number
}
```

This one trows errors.

In my code:

`let result: MergedInterfaces [][] | ??? = [];`

Any idea how to declare this one?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**For that multi-dimensional object, you could declare like this:**

```
 type Data = {
   type: string;
   what: string;
   from?: string;
   to?: string;
   fee?: string;
   blockNumber?: number;
   transactionHash?: string;
   oracleRequestId?: string;
   output?: string;
 }[][];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQFwngDgpsAiCGJ7ALzAN4Chg-NAXMAM4gBOAlgHYDmA3NjgO4AWihJFN9OwAZqQHsAtgH52ZKnQagBY4hK7TeUKHI6TuOAEYAbAQGMA1gDkArkK1RScyuculNoUvEpF4+kOQGUAEvCLMagpSPALO+jpQAEpQAI6mUCQAkgAmQZwhOAKmIBA56RrYAL4A2gC65fSY+t4kwCmI8IQISKjAJQwdPBjSPHhQhADkgwA0vUysIEOj43yCQtNj3bgCi7PKA8DDS8u6BiZ2VoQADDvdZC5uHl6+-sxry8Bh7pEx8YkgqQ88RWc9j-1vt0WGwtjMAc5XO5PN4-AEgTw9kYzBYjsBTrNnhFonEEskUgisjk8lMwX9fgwyjsujwsADIJttrMQaSmY9+MJCTIuRsuUiDqjSCc-rhIVcYbd4WTMeFXriPl9pd0Kd06ctAUrliyuRcoddYXc+XpkYcheiRU9ZTj3viudlcjkESrgFTMGV6EA)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
type CommonFields = {type: string, what: string, blockNumber: number, transactionHash: string, oracleRequestId: string}
type FromTo = {from: string, to: string, fee: string} & CommonFields
type Output = {output: string} & CommonFields
type ArrayOfData = [FromTo, Output][]
```

In this way, you can generalize types and reuse them. Think of better naming ofc.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgMQJYQDYBMDOUAvFAN6iQBcU%20wAThigOYA0UA7gBYCGw1tDZmwBG2OAGMA1gDkArgmEQ61FPMV029binzdxwDKgAS3fJ371GrKHDp7sEAEoQAjrIi0AkrguCmAXwAoCmg0OkQAFThiMgAzcIRfK004JKEoWIgINICoADJYRGR0LDx8YPBoAHlZYDBamNI4Wvq%20Gktmf3zCpFRMHAIKyCgAQTo7ECrYgBFebhiAbTDIuDYautqAXQXNwMDxVFooXDnqMYmp2eB5kgXAqCg7h4fSe%20eHkOoAci%20WN-euLxvr9-s94ohgX93h9UlAflDoZlsnCQdCoKIJDI1EpqAAGBHvLQ6PQGYymcwognPWz2JyudxeHyU0H%20KmvNGfZlowFteGgj52Yn6QwoExmSH89FiKRyBQ4qD4yU08QOZxuDzAbwStHNDa81HPVlvTYIp7PdnQzl87k8fVUh7gxJcy2w62IrLa6EYmXY5QK%201QIm6YVk8XO97K1X0jVa8NQI3vC2EyqegG21PPIMkkViilu97erFyv2KnV2FV09WMjMPXWtDMJqAmwKbADcgSAA)